# Auto Save a file in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to find a way where by we can auto save a file in Firefox using JS. The way I have done till yet using FireShot on a Windows Desktop:

```
var element = content.document.createElement("FireShotDataElement");
element.setAttribute("Entire", EntirePage);
element.setAttribute("Action", Action);
element.setAttribute("Key", Key);
element.setAttribute("BASE64Content", "");
element.setAttribute("Data", Data);
element.setAttribute("Document", content.document);
if (typeof(CapturedFrameId) != "undefined")
  element.setAttribute("CapturedFrameId", CapturedFrameId);
content.document.documentElement.appendChild(element);
var evt = content.document.createEvent("Events");
evt.initEvent("capturePageEvt", true, false);
element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

But the issue is that it opens a dialog box to confirm the local drive location details. Is there a way I can hard code the local drive storage location and auto save the file?

Comment: So, are you creating a Firefox add-on? Or are you asking how you can modify/configure FireShot? Or are you asking for a FireShot alternative? Please note that questions on Stack Overflow are supposed to relate to programming - and right now I don't see that relation in your question (not that the question itself is really clear).

Comment: Yes I am creating a Fire Fox add-on. Above is the code stating how I have currently implemented the requirement which does not suits to what I wanted to achieve. As such I am looking for a JS script that can auto-save a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a Firefox add-on then [FileUtils](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm) and [NetUtil.asyncCopy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules/NetUtil.jsm#asyncCopy%28%29) are your friends:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");

var TEST_DATA = "this is a test string";
var source = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"].
                 createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIStringInputStream);
source.setData(TEST_DATA, TEST_DATA.length);

var file = new FileUtils.File("c:\\foo\\bar.txt");
var sink = file.openSafeFileOutputStream(file, FileUtils.MODE_WRONLY |
                                               FileUtils.MODE_CREATE);
NetUtil.asyncCopy(source, sink);
```

This will asynchronously write the string `this is a test string` into the file `c:\foo\bar.txt`. Note that `NetUtil.asyncCopy` closes both streams automatically, you don't need to do it. However, you might want to pass a function as third parameter to this method - it will be called when the write operation is finished.

See also: [Code snippets, writing to a file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Writing_to_a_file)

Answer (score 0):

Every computer has a different file structure. But still, there is a way. You can save it to cookie / session, depends on how "permanent" your data wants to be.

Do not consider writing a physical file as it requires extra permission.

Comment: I am using Windows Desktop and need to write to local drive only